# Получение выписки из ФГИС ЕГРН через web сервисы

Tags: soap

Нам необходимо автоматизировать процесс получения выписки из ФГИС ЕГРП посредством web сервиса росрееста, о котором везде говорят, но какая либо информация с описанием протокола прямого взаимодействия отсутствует. 
Взаимодействие посредством сторонних сервисов предоставляющих API росрееста нам известны, но не подходят. 
Ответа от росреестра не можем получить уже пятый день.

Было бы очень здорово найти, более-менее, полную информацию всего процесса взамодействия, поскольку единственной отправной точкой которой мы на данный момент располагаем является данный документ https://rosreestr.ru/site/upload/documenty/doc_doc_Opisanie_servisa.docx в котором описаны общие детали взаимодействия, но отсутствует информация по формату документа (для запроса) на получение выписки из ЕГРН. 
Сам же документ с описанием протокола был описан до формирования ЕГРН (возможно кому нибудь известен более актуальный источник с описанием протокола?).

Нас интересует след. информация:

- Где найти наиболее актуальную информацию о протоколе прямого взаимодействия (или мы прибегаем к наиболее актуальной из доступных)?
- Где найти формат документа для формирования запроса на выписку из ЕГРН?
- Как автоматизировать процесс шифрования (в приведенном документе описано ручное выполнение данного процесса в приложении #2 используя программу КриптоАРМ). 
  Нашел данную инструкцию https://armrus.org/extranet/forum-egrn-kluba/index.php/forum36/6190-https-po-gost-na-linux (справедлива ли она в нашем случае?).

За помощь с возникшими сложностями (ввиду дефицита информации), выразим скромную, финансовую благодарность.